# 3way between subjects Anova with Unbalanced samples

Tags: r, anova, robust

I would like to perform robust 3-way ANOVA using the WRS package in R. The very first requirement is to cast the data into wide format. Hence, I have wide format data frame with unbalanced rows in each groups. With this unbalanced samples, R refused to proceed with the robust anova test using the command of `t3way(3, 2, 2, Datasetwide)`. I get this error message: `Error in if (chkit$teststat > chkit$crit) break : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed.`
Can anyone advise on what should I do?

Comment: Have you tried the updated WRS2 package? It allows a formula version (and I believe) a long data format. This new package seems a bit more straight-forward and prone to fewer error messages.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Have tried WRS2 package but still somehow stuck.

Answer (score 1):

After checking with Wilcox's book, the data needs to be stored in list mode, which is neither wide nor long. Basically, each element of `listA[[i]]` is a vector for each permutation of the levels within your factor. It's a bit clunky, but once you organise your data in this way, there should not be a problem.

See below for example code using WRS.

```
library(WRS)
#Use a loop to create a data set containing a 3x2x2 factorial experiment
myMeans=c(10, 15, 20, 10, 11, 10, 9, 9.5, 9, 10, 11, 10)
set.seed(1)
mySD=rnorm(n=12, mean = 2, sd = .5)
set.seed(1)
myN=round(rnorm(12, 50, 10), 0)
myData=list(level1=NA)
for(i in 1:12){
  set.seed(i)
  myData[[i]]=rnorm(50, myMeans[i], mySD[i])
}
#Give the variables more sensible names based on the design
names(myData)[1:3]=paste("1.1", 1:3, sep=".")#Names are FactorA.FactorB.FactorC
names(myData)[4:6]=paste("1.2", 1:3, sep=".")
names(myData)[7:9]=paste("2.1", 1:3, sep=".")
names(myData)[10:12]=paste("2.2", 1:3, sep=".")
#Plot the data to get a sense of what the results look like
boxplot(myData, col=rep(c("orange", "darkorange2", "lightgreen", "forestgreen"), c(3,3,3,3)))
abline(v=6.5, lwd=2)
abline(v=c(3.5, 9.5), lty=2)
#Run the robust ANOVA with a 20% trimming. the grp argument is unnecessary in this example because the variables are in the right order in the list, but it is included for compelteness. 
t3way(3,2,2, myData, tr = .2, grp=1:12)
```

Comment: Many thanks for the reply. I tried m long dataset with WRS2 and it works finally. I guess it was stuck due to all the try-and-error commands I tried and they messed up the program. I wrote to the author of WRS 2 and his reply was WRS 2 t3way command can work on long dataset and slightly unbalanced samples. Anyway, really appreciate your effort.